# Tomcat AccessLogValve keep all files on disk forever?

Tags: tomcat6

Tomcat AccessLogValve keep all files on disk forever?
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: And what is your problem? Can't guess it from what you write... :-S

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the fact that Tomcat blocks file access to logs once it's running, so that you can't delete/move/edit these files once the server is up?

If so, then you just need to have some kind of clean up script running in your restart/startup batch.

If not then I really don't understand the question.

Could you provide more info?